# How to hide/remove the border of the particular row in qtable widget using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Here in my program i want to delete the rectangular border for my second row of the Qtablewidget.Here i am using grid(False)it changing the entire table.Can any one please tell me how to hide/remove the border of the second row of the tablewidget.Thank you in advance.
Given below is my code:

```
    self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    self.table_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setRowCount(2)
    self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
    self.table.setColumnCount(6)
    self.fnt = self.table.font()
    self.fnt.setPointSize(20)
    self.table.setFont(self.fnt)
    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("S.no, Item Description,Qty,Rate(Rs:),Subtotal,"",").split(','))
    self.newvbox.addWidget(self.table)
    # self.table.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode( QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
    header.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    header.setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setResizeMode(2, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    header.setResizeMode(3, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    header.setResizeMode(4, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    self.btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton(icon=QtGui.QIcon("./plus.png"))
    self.table.setCellWidget(1,0,self.btn1)
    self.table.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(1)))
```

Comment: I'll allow the question change since no answers have been posted yet.

Comment: In SO a post is only for a single question, that's why the button says **Ask Question**, it does not say **Ask Questions**